# AngularJS: How to make local variables work which are not part of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an application where I am receiving a list of person objects in persons and iterating over to build a table dynamically.

The code looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat = "personInfo in persons">
    <td>{{personInfo.name}}</td>
    <td>{{personInfo.gender}}</td>
    <td>
      <select ng-model="selected_address" ng-options="address.placename for address in personInfo.address"></select>
      <span ng-show="make_address_editable==false;">{{selected_address.address}}</span>
      <input type="text" style="width: 22em;" ng-show="make_address_editable" ng-model="selected_address.address" />
      <input style="margin-left: 2em;" type="button" value="{{btnValue}}" ng-show="selected_address" ng-click="make_address_editable=!make_address_editable; changeBtnValue($index)"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The part where I am stuck is how to change the value of input[type="button"] or {{btnValue}} individually for each person which edits/saves a person's address. I don't want to assign it as a property on the personInfo object as I would not need it later. In my controller I initialize the value of make_address_editable and btValue but I'm only able to control the behavior of make_address_editable on ng-click for each person. If I call a function on ng-click which changes btnValue depending on what the user clicked it changes the btnValue for each row/person.

Controller code:

```
$scope.make_address_editable = false;
$scope.btnValue = 'Edit';
$scope.changeBtnValue = function(index){
  if ($scope.btnValue === 'Edit'){
    $scope.btnValue = 'Save';
  }
  else{
    $scope.btnValue = 'Edit';
  }
}
```

I don't know how to use index in the method to change btnValue for each person in the table.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a plunker / runnable sample?  I am not visualizing what you're trying change. and what problem you're experiencing trying to change it.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/552Ug/2/. It's not working for some reason but what I want to do is in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem including a btnValue within the personInfo object as this is a ViewModel and you are really driving the view (value of button) based on what is in that model. You may not be using it later in terms of using that value when persisting the person to a datastore, but your view is definitely using it constantly as it is keeping the two-way binding in sync.

You should really be putting make_address_editable inside your personInfo model as well since I don't think you want to have a "global" flag for each individual person. Having make_address_editable directly on $scope will prevent you from tracking it on a person by person basis.

If you really must make a local variable, you can try this. See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/552Ug/4/) I made starting with your example:

```
angular.module('coolApp', [])
    .controller('PersonCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.persons = [{'name': 'Alex', 'gender': 'Male', 'address': [{'placename': 'Home', 'address': '1234 Dr'},{'placename': 'Office', 'address': '12345 Dr'}]}, {'name': 'Alexis', 'gender': 'Female', 'address': [{'placename': 'Home', 'address': '12345 Dr'},{'placename': 'Office', 'address': '123456 Dr'}]}];

    //$scope.make_address_editable = false;
    //$scope.btnValue = 'Edit';
    $scope.changeBtnValue = function (viewModel) {
        if (viewModel.editable === true) {
            viewModel.btnValue = 'Save';
        } else {
            viewModel.btnValue = 'Edit';
        }
    };
});
```

Then use ng-init within your repeater to make a viewModel object that is local to the repeater scope. This will keep your persons from changing:

```
<div ng-app="coolApp">
    <div ng-controller="PersonCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="personInfo in persons" ng-init="viewModel={btnValue: 'Edit', editable: false}">
                <td>{{personInfo.name}}</td>
                <td>{{personInfo.gender}}</td>
                <td>
                    <select ng-model="selected_address" ng-options="address.placename for address in personInfo.address"></select> <span ng-show="viewModel.editable===false;">{{selected_address.address}}</span>

                    <input type="text" style="width: 22em;" ng-show="viewModel.editable" ng-model="selected_address.address" />
                    <input style="margin-left: 2em;" type="button" value="{{viewModel.btnValue}}" ng-show="selected_address" ng-click="viewModel.editable=!viewModel.editable; changeBtnValue(viewModel);" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <br><br>
    {{persons}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. I was doing that earlier but I was having to save 6 more variables in the personInfo object for keeping track of other changes in each row like showing/hiding error messages, editing other fields etc. I am planning to send the final persons array to it's parent page so I don't want to send these additional fields which are only applicable to this page.

Comment: If you want to send data to the parent page, then the most "angular way" to do it would probably be with a PersonFactory. The page would still have a persons array used specifically for that view, but the changes made would affect a person within the PersonFactory array that would be passed back to your parent page.

Answer (score 0):

btnValue is supposed to change for all "persons". But I think you'd want it to change for specific "person" objects only.

There is an ugly way to do this. Pass the event to the function.

```
ng-click="make_address_editable=!make_address_editable; changeBtnValue($event)"
```

Inside the changeBtnValue function, change the "value" attribute of the corresponding input tag.

```
$scope.changeBtnValue = function(event){
          var inputTag = event.target;
}
```

"inputTag" variable will hold HTML Element object representing the corresponding input tag. Change the "value" attribute of the tag to "save"/"edit" or anything else.
THis method is ugly because you manipulate the View from within the JS code. People usually try to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks @ArjunKumar. I really don't want to manipulate my DOM directly. I want to do it the "angular" way.

Comment: the angular way would be to attach btnValue to person person is a a model representing the view state,or it wouldnt be in the controller.

Comment: Then you'd have to follow @Patrick's answer. On a sidenote, "make_address_editable" and "btnValue" if only used within this snippet, seem unnecessary. There are ways to just do it within the HTML page using only one variable. Use ng-value to change the value of the input tag based on conditions.

Comment: @ArjunKumar: Can you give me an example of how can I do that using ng-value? I am not too familiar with that attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Patrick's answer seems to solve your problem. But either way, you don't have to call a function to change the value of the input tag. Use ng-value on the variable created by ng-init. I edited @Patrick's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/552Ug/6/).

Comment: I had already mentioned that this answer does not conform to AngularJS conventions. I chose to present the answer because that is what OP wanted to know. Why did this get downvoted? Ugh.